# check each object, return true when the first condition is met, else return false

Tags: java, lambda

I have a method that works fine. This is how it looks.

```
private ArrayList<Car> carsInStore ; //in car class have setter/getter/quals/Constructor.
```

```
public boolean checkIfcarInStore(Car c) {   
    for (Car car : carsInStore) {
        if(car.equals(c)){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I want to switch this to Lambda.

But I am not sure how fill in the `if` (condition) return `true` or return `false` outside.

And I know I can do it in stream too. Can anyone give an example?

Comment: Actually, even `carsInStore.contains(c)` should work

Comment: By the way, I made an error in my previous (now deleted) comment. The correct (but useless given the above comment) way to do that with a stream would be [`carsInStore.stream().anyMatch(c::equals)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Stream.html#anyMatch(java.util.function.Predicate)) (assuming `c` is the `Car` you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to use `lambda`, this should work else you have your answer within your comment.

```
private ArrayList<Car> carsInStore ;

public boolean checkIfcarInStore(Car c) {   
    return carsInStore.stream().anyMatch(c::equals);
    }
 }
```

Comment: you the best...thanks you, but it just stream ...can we do it with lamda?..

Answer (score 0):

You can substitute the method `checkIfcarInStore()` with a [`Predicate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/function/Predicate.html), which is a *functional interface* representing a boolean condition, that can be implemented as a *lambda expression*:

```
Predicate<Car> isInStore = car -> carsInStore.contains(car);
```

or as a *method reference*:

```
Predicate<Car> isInStore = carsInStore::contains;
```

If according to the instructions of your assignment you need to have a method `checkIfcarInStore()`, the *predicate* can be declared as a field and used internally inside the method:

```
private ArrayList<Car> carsInStore ;
private Predicate<Car> isInStore = car -> carsInStore.contains(car);
    
public boolean checkIfCarInStore(Car car) {
    return isInStore.test(car);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I know I can change the methot. But the instructions say do not change and use boolean method...can you give a exmple..with both...i mean stream and lamda ...

Comment: @avirammoalem If according to the instructions of your assignment you need to have a method `checkIfcarInStore()`, you can declare predicate as a field and use it internally inside the method.

Comment: @avirammoalem The key thing related to lambda expressions you have to know is that it needs to conform to a *functional interface*, you can't use lambdas anywhere you like. To be on the same page, I suggest you to have a look at this [tutorial provided by Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html). I've updated the answer.

Comment: @avirammoalem Stream is redundant here. If you need to use Stream IPA according to your assignment, then you have to specify it in the question. Stream is not the same as lambda expression, you can use lambda inside the stream. It's really the core knowledge, no "rocket science", take a look at the tutorial I've previously mentioned.

Comment: thanks you.I saw the post now
Thanks I willearn from there